# Error setting breakpoint in Visual Studio Code C++ Debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Until last week I was able to hit breakpoints in my C++ code in VSCode. Since last two days when I try to attach the debugger to the remote process, the breakpoints grey out.

On bringing my mouse pointer on a greyed out breakpoint, the message says:

> Error setting breakpoint. The debug engine threw an exception.

, as shown in the image below:

[image: Failed Breakpoint Image]

---

My `launch.json` looks like the following:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "prgAttach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "~/JBL/SC-253/bin/azg",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        //Followed by other debug configurations...
    ]
}
```

---

My platform info, obtained from Code > About Visual Studio Code, is:

```
Version: 1.41.1
Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Date: 2019-12-18T14:57:51.166Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0
```

---

Anyone else familiar with the problem? Any suggestions/workarounds?

I have:

- tried uninstalling the C/C++ extensions and reinstalled them. No effect.
- verified that I'm attaching to the correct process.
- restarted the process too, to do a fresh attach.

Comment: Why don't you try checking out a revision of your code from one or two weeks ago from your version control software and see if that still works? If it does, then simply bisect commits between then and your HEAD revision to find the change that broke things for you..

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The debugger fails to attach to the very first line that accepts a connection over the socket. Nevertheless I tried your suggestion. The debugger is behaving the same way with older code too.

Comment: ohh well. Worth a try :)

Comment: Did you check the debugger output tab (or other output tabs) to see if there is any additional info?  Is the remote process on the same system or on a different one (maybe there's a change in firewall/network settings blocking the connection)?  Do you have appropriate (admin) priviliges everywhere?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: The debugger output tab looks good with every line ending with "Symbols Loaded." There's one warning in the last line, but my faint memory tells that it was present earlier too. This last line says - _Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64. =thread-selected,id="1"_. The process I'm attaching to, is on my machine. So no firewall issue. Privileges issue also seem unlikely. VSCode asked me for permission to attach and I granted it immediately.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, 1201ProgramAlarm: Confirmed with another co-worker - same problem. This isn't a code issue. This is an IDE issue.

Comment: Am I correct, that breakpoints worked for a program launched from MSVS until you connected to a remote process and then stopped working altogether? Or do they still work when a program is launched from MSVS? If the issue is only for the remote process, do you have it compiled with debugging information (debug MSVS config or, if you are using compilation from a command line debug compiler options)?

Comment: @isp-zax: The question isn’t about MSVS. It is about VSC. And i was able to attach VSC debugger to the remote process earlier without an issue. Now the debugger fails to set the breakpoints as shown in the image added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that your issue could be related to this (you don't provide your full platform information): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3829

LLDB itself still works, it's just broken from within VS Code, but a fix is in the works according to the link.

It could also be worth re-generating launch.json and trying that out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there are no real answers to this issue is that the debugging ability is due to an extension you may have added. The inability to set a breakpoint, is likely due to some bug in that extension.

---

**Workaround:**

You do not need to use the debugger you have been using so far in Visual Studio Code. Since the IDE is heavily extension supported, you can find and install another debugger and modify `launch.json` to use the new installation.

At the time of writing this answer, just typing `lldb` in the search tab of *Extensions: Marketplace* (Mac keyboard shortcut - <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>) lists some seven possible debugging extensions that you can install, three of which pertain to C/C++.

---

Whichever debugging extension you install, will have a Quick Start or similar guide that will explain how to modify the `launch.json` to enable debugging with the new extension. Remove or comment out the configuration entries for older debugger so that it doesn't interfere.